# Apply a module layout to zfcuser

Tags: layout, zend-framework2, zfcuser

i'm working on zf2 and try to use 2 differents layouts. 1 layout for a public module and another one (private layout") for all the others. Its works pretty well but my zfcuser module in the public module use the other layout :/
i tried this :

```
'template_map' => array(  
    'zfc-user/user/login' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/blank.phtml', // blank is my public layout 
),
```

Instead of get the form in my layout, i get my form in the public layout AND in the "private" layout ...
Does someone can help me ?

Comment: Check https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts

Comment: Thanks for the link but i already saw Evan's plugin and i didn't want to use it for only 2 layout.

Comment: Well, check [`Module#onBootstrap()`](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts/blob/master/Module.php#L9-L15), that's how it is done... You can't make it smaller than this

Comment: I checked http://blog.evan.pro/module-specific-layouts-in-zend-framework-2#comment-44930 too, this way i don't need the edpmodulelayouts (that didn't fix my problem). I'm still looking for the way to apply layout on my zfcuser..

Comment: Once again, if yout want to set a Layout for a Module that you did not program yourself, you NEED EdpModuleLayouts (or rewrite it to your specific needs). I don't understand what your Problem with this is ^^

Comment: I set 2 differents layout : 
- layout/blank > site module
- layout/layout > other module
Zfc-user is in my site module but it display the other module layout :/ 
Does it's clear like this ? :p

Comment: You need to listen to the right namespace. If you replace `__NAMESPACE__` with `'ZfcUser'` in the code evan provided here http://blog.evan.pro/module-specific-layouts-in-zend-framework-2#comment-44930 it should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks Crisp, it display the right layout in ZfcUser, now i just have to remove this error and everything will be ok : "Use of undefined constant ZfcUser"

Comment: did you miss the quotes, I edited my comments to include them, should be `'ZfcUser'` not `ZfcUser`

Comment: Only need to use quotes on ZfcUser ;) Crisp can you edit your post as solution and i will notice that it solve my issue. edit : yes forgot the quotes :p

Comment: No problem, and done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code evan provides here http://blog.evan.pro/module-specific-layouts-in-zend-framework-2 will do what you need with one minor change, replace `__NAMESPACE__` with `'ZfcUser'` so that you're listening for ZfcUser controller actions

```
public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
{
        $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEvents->attach('ZfcUser', 'dispatch', function($e) {
        // This event will only be fired when an ActionController under the ZfcUser namespace is dispatched.
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $controller->layout('layout/alternativelayout');
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: I also add your solution in evan's blog if other people are looking for it. Thanks you.

Comment: Dead link.  Can someone post the answer here?

Comment: @Bluebaron, the code in the link is virtually identical to the code above, only the event identifier changes (`zfcuser` above, `MyModule` in the original), but anyway, the wayback machine link is here showing the original post -> http://web.archive.org/web/20120514011812/http://blog.evan.pro/module-specific-layouts-in-zend-framework-2

Answer (score 0):

Added to composer.json

```
"evandotpro/edp-module-layouts": "1.0"
```

Created /module/Application/view/layout/blank.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->content;
```

Added this to /config/autoload/global.php

```
return array(
'module_layouts' => array(
    'ZfcUser' => 'layout/blank'
));
```

Finally to /module/Application/config/module.config.php

```
'view_manager' => array(

    'template_map' => array(

        //add this line
        'layout/blank' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/blank.phtml',
```